# Event emitter, object is not function

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling

I created an event in node.js but when I try to trigger the event and pass arguments to the callback I get `eventEmitter("dataIn", null, message); TypeError: object is not a function`. Looking at similar stack overflow questions the problem was not using `new` to create the eventEmitter, but I am.

First I setup the event.

```
 var events = require('events').EventEmitter;
 var eventEmitter = new events();
```

Then I set the callback.

```
 function dataIn(config, callback) {
   if(typeof callback === 'function') {

     /* Set the callback for the dataIn event. */
     eventEmitter.on("dataIn", callback);

     /* More code below. */
```

Finally when I try to emit the event I get the type error.

```
var message = {
  "type": "REQUEST"
}

var rtrn = eventEmitter("dataIn", null, message);
if(rtrn === false) {
  console.log('Error triggering event');
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't it be `eventEmitter.emit("dataIn", message)` to trigger the event ?

Comment: I thought so too, but it was not working and then I saw this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419064/why-is-my-node-event-callback-showing-up-in-the-event-as-undefined and then it worked. I think the first argument is reserved for error.

Comment: Well, yes, I meant the `emit` part really, but if your callback is written the usual Node fashion, accepting arguments like `foo(error, response)` you'd have to pass `null` as the error as well

Comment: I see, I miss read your comment the first time.

Comment: Thank you 2trill2spill you solved my question, because of you said a lot of other question related to having problems with EventEmitter were that they did not instantiate it with new.

Comment: @enoy Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EventEmitter instance isn't a function; you're trying to call it as if it were.  You need to call the `.emit()` method:

```
eventEmitter.emit("dataIn", null, message);
```